# Tkinter Focus lost after askstring

Tags: python, tkinter, focus

I am currently implementing a program that uses many tkinter frames and while subframe is being opened I want the superframe to be locked for the user (otherwise things will not work out). After some research I found the grab_set and grab_release method which worked quite fine.

However once the subframe (instanciated by Toplevel) calls the askstring the grab is "losed" and the user can interact with the superlevel window again. An example would be this (very simplified code):

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()
def open_sublevel():
    tl = tk.Toplevel(root)
    def ask():
        print(tk.simpledialog.askstring("askstring", "askstring"))
    tk.Button(tl, text="ask", command=ask).pack()
    tl.grab_set()
    root.wait_window(tl)
    tl.grab_release()
    print("release")


tk.Button(root, text="asdf", command=open_sublevel).pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Once the user opens the subframe by clicking "asdf" the frame containing "asdf" will be locked for the duration while the subframe is opened. However once the user selects the "ask"-Button in the subframe this "lock" somehow disappears.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. It might also help to know what platform you are using.

Comment: Well the minimal example is not so minimal... I would have to post all modules and submodules for it to be a verificable, since the superlevel module imports various other modules I wrote.

Comment: I simplified it as much as I could and posted the code into the original post (which is compilable on every python 3.X). I am working on Windows10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the notes in the tkinter library:

> A grab directs all events to this and descendant widgets in the application.

I am not able so far to find any documentation that would explain why the `grab_set()` is falling off after you finish submitting your `askstring` but I would imaging it is because once the widget is gone the `grab_set()` falls off. Just like if you were to close out the `Toplevel` window.

In this case `tl.grab_release()` does not appear to be needed as grab releases once the window closes.

From what I have tested if you reset the `grab_set()` after the `askstring` is done then it will still work properly.

You need to simply add `tl.grab_set()` just below `print(tk.simpledialog.askstring("askstring", "askstring"))`.

Modified code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog

root = tk.Tk()

def open_sublevel():
    tl = tk.Toplevel(root)
    tl.grab_set()

    def ask():
        print(tk.simpledialog.askstring("askstring", "askstring"))
        tl.grab_set()

    tk.Button(tl, text="ask", command=ask).pack()
    print("release")

tk.Button(root, text="asdf", command=open_sublevel).pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

setting the parent for simpledialog will make simpledialog take focus

x = simpledialog(parent = window_x, title = z etc.)

this will make sure x takes focus and not withdraw